# using <picture> tag with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, explorer, polyfills

Have been searching the internet for a while and no solution.

I am trying to use slick carousel with the new picture tag, works great in every browser but IE 11. does anyone know about a workaround/polyfill for IE 11?

Answer (score 18):

The `<picture>` tag is part of HTML5 but on the documentation, the fallback is `<img>` which will even work on old browsers.

```html
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 64em)" src="high-res.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" src="med-res.jpg">
   <source src="low-res.jpg">
   <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="This picture loads on non-supporting browsers.">
   <p>Accessible text.</p>
</picture>
```

Comment: Thanks Zuch, I have different images that loads in different widths, I will have to find a workaround for IE11

Comment: @Lucky500 Cant, you just set width and height per image that has different widths?

Comment: as it is right now, browser chooses the appropriate image depending on the width of the browser window. on IE11, it only loads the default image, ignoring the source tags. So, I will have to only work with one image for IE and position it accordingly. Other option would be write a script to swap images for IE, but I don't think I am going that route.

Answer (score 7):

The standard `<picture>` polyfill is [Picturefill](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/). It should allow the element to work as expected in IE8+.

Comment: The Picturefill polyfill doesn't seem to be actively maintained though

Comment: Fair, though it's remarkably stable (none of the open issues are particularly concerning) and is in broad use.