# WEBP support for legacy browsers using <picture>

Tags: image, internet-explorer-11, webp

I'm using the following code in hopes of supporting IE11 and Safari (iOS11). The desired behavior is for the WEBP image to load on browsers that support ita and the PNG to load in IE11/iOS11 (where WEBP is not supported.) I'm using a (slightly) similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957262/using-picture-tag-with-internet-explorer-11) here as a reference.

```
<picture>
<source srcset="image.png" type="image/png">
<source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
<img src="image.png">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show webp image in Chrome and png image in IE11, you need to **put the webp source at first**. You can refer to the following code, it shows rose (png image) in IE 11 and tree (webp image) in Chrome:

```html
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.webp">
  <source type="image/png" srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png">
</picture>
```